# 'this' implicitly has type 'any'

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

```
interface ob {
  [key: string]: string
}

function DrawFillSVG(options: ob) {
  this.options = extend({}, this.options);
  extend(this.options, options);
  this._init();
}
```

The error says:

```
 TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation
```

But am not clear on how to go about it, any help will be apperciated

Comment: Use a `class DrawFillSVG` instead?

Comment: show whole file

Comment: what is options ??

Answer (score 0):

The function `this` type annotation goes like:

```
function DrawFillSVG(this: whateverType, options: ob) {
  this.options = extend({}, this.options);
  extend(this.options, options);
  this._init();
```